# Install Vowpal Wabbit on Cloudera Hadoop Vmware Image

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, centos, cloudera, vowpalwabbit

When I try to install Vowpal Wabbit on Cloudera Hadoop (VmWare Image) using [this URL](http://synckey.github.io/hadoop/2015/06/09/run-vw-on-hadoop/) I keep getting this error:

```
    [root@quickstart vowpal_wabbit-7.10]# sudo make install

    Making install in vowpalwabbit
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/cloudera/vowpal_wabbit-7.10/vowpalwabbit'
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -I/usr/include -I/include  -Wall -Wno-unused-local-typedef  -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DNDEBUG     -pedantic  -std=gnu++11 -L/usr/lib64 -lboost_program_options-mt -L/lib -lz -lpthread  -o vw vw-main.o libvw.la liballreduce.la 
libtool: link: g++ -I/usr/include -I/include -Wall -Wno-unused-local-typedef -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DNDEBUG -pedantic -std=gnu++11 -o .libs/vw vw-main.o  -L/usr/lib64 -L/lib ./.libs/libvw.so /home/cloudera/vowpal_wabbit-7.10/vowpalwabbit/.libs/liballreduce.so ./.libs/liballreduce.so -lboost_program_options-mt -lz -lpthread -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib
./.libs/libvw.so: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::get_canonical_option_prefix()'
./.libs/libvw.so: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::error_with_option_name(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&, int)'
./.libs/libvw.so: undefined reference to `vtable for boost::program_options::error_with_option_name'
./.libs/libvw.so: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::what() const'
./.libs/libvw.so: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'
./.libs/libvw.so: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
./.libs/libvw.so: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validation_error::get_template(boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t)'
./.libs/libvw.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::program_options::error_with_option_name'
./.libs/libvw.so: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [vw] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/cloudera/vowpal_wabbit-7.10/vowpalwabbit'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: The web page you're referring to copies the boost program_option library to `./libs` using `cp /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.so.1.58.0 ./libs/ `  but `vw` expects it in `./.libs` thus the error in runtime linking.  You need to keep both consistent.  Anyway relying on env vars like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for things to run in different environments is prone to inconsistency errors and not recommended.  Building/linking statically is a saner way to go. See my other answer/comment to you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) after lots of effort i was unable to install this library on cloudera but successfully installed on ubunto 12 version.

Comment: My point is that if you build vw statically, you never need to worry about cloudera/red-hat/ubuntu setting up things differently.  You can use the same statically built `vw` on all Linux 64-bit platforms and the same binary just works everywhere.  It will also save you a lot of work.  You may find a few prebuilt binaries (by me) at: http://finance.yendor.com/ML/VW/Binaries/   please verify checksums.